# Android- Error Message

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, android-edittext

I have been recently having an error when compiling my android code onto an emulator. The game is that when you click a button, it gives you a math question displayed on a textView, and user types their answer (in numbers) and clicks the button 'check' When I click that button, it always returns false.
Anyone knows how to fix this?

**Java Class**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);




    mathQuestion = findViewById(R.id.magic_textview);

    redCircle = findViewById(R.id.math_ball);

    yellowbox = findViewById(R.id.yellow_box);
    yellowboxY = 1550f - 130f;
    yellowbox.setY(yellowboxY);
    yellowboxX = 472f;
    yellowbox.setX(yellowboxX);


    type_answer = findViewById(R.id.type_answer);
    Button checkButton = findViewById(R.id.check_button);
    checkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(redCircleX == yellowboxX && redCircleY == yellowboxY){
                mathQuestion.setText("What is "+math_int1+" + "+math_int2+" ?");
                math_int1 = r.nextInt(20);
                math_int2 = r.nextInt(20)+1;
                string_math_int1 = String.valueOf(math_int1);
                string_math_int2 = String.valueOf(math_int2);
                Button checkAnswer = findViewById(R.id.check_answer);
                 checkAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(View view) {

                        //Error? Always returning false?

                         if (type_answer.getText().toString().contains (Integer.toString( math_int1 + math_int2))) {
                            Toast t =  Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            t.show();
                         } else {
                            Toast t2= Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, type_answer.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            t2.show();

                         }



                       }


                 });

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, "Incorrect Or Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });



    Button upButton = findViewById(R.id.up_button);
    upButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            moveUp();

        }
    });
    Button downButton = findViewById(R.id.down_button);
    downButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            moveDown();

        }
    });


    Button leftButton = findViewById(R.id.left_button);
    leftButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            moveLeft();

        }
    });
    Button rightButton = findViewById(R.id.right_button);
    rightButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            moveRight();

        }
    });
    Button resetCircleXY = findViewById(R.id.reset_button);
    resetCircleXY.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            initCircleXY();
            Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, "Reset Ball's Position", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    upButton.performClick();
    leftButton.performClick();
    redCircleY = 1550f;
    redCircle.setY(redCircleY);
    redCircleX = 472f;
    redCircle.setX(redCircleX);


}

private void moveUp(){
    redCircleY -= ballMoveDis;
    redCircle.setY(redCircleY);

}
private void moveDown(){
    redCircleY += ballMoveDis;
    redCircle.setY(redCircleY);

}

private void moveLeft(){
    redCircleX += ballMoveDis;
    redCircle.setX(redCircleX);

}
private void moveRight(){
    redCircleX -= ballMoveDis;
    redCircle.setX(redCircleX);

}
private void initCircleXY(){
    redCircleY = 1550f;
    redCircle.setY(redCircleY);
    redCircleX = 472f;
    redCircle.setX(redCircleX);
}
```

}

Help is greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Answer to newly formatted question:*

Your issue has to do with comparing two strings when you want to check their int values. You could try using `Integer.parseInt()` on your `EditText`'s entry. Just be aware you will need to do a try on it to catch an exception in the case of your `EditText` having any non numeric characters.

*Answer to previous question about crash before edit:*

Your crash isn't with your `EditText`. It is this line:

`Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this,math_int1 + math_int2 , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

By passing it an int value, it is attempting to look up a string with that id. If your intent is to display the sum of those ints, it should look something like:

`Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, String.valueOf(math_int1 + math_int2), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: Thank you for that, its just now, it always returns false

Comment: Your issue has something to do with how you are comparing strings. You could try using `Integer.parseInt()` on your `EditText`'s entry. Just be aware you will need to do a try on it to catch an exception in the case of your `EditText` having any non numeric characters.

Comment: Thank you, it fixed my problem.

Comment: Just a heads up. It's not usually good practice to heavily edit your question, particularly when it received an answer that resolved your initial issue.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will pay more attention in editing my posts

Answer (score 0):

First mistake

```
string_math_int1 = String.valueOf(math_int1);
string_math_int2 = String.valueOf(math_int1);  // this should be math_int2
```

BUT consider adding two strings

```
 string_math_int1 + string_math_int2)

 "10"             +  "20"
```

equals

```
 "1020" not "30"
```

Maybe

```
if (type_answer.getText().toString().equals(String.valueOf (math_int1 + math_int2) {
```

Comment: Thanks, but my app still crashes for the same reason

Comment: And you have not told us what that reason is, post the relevant portion of your log

Comment: post the relevant portion of your log, I don't know if you are dealing with a NPE

Comment: What do you mean, the error message? On the logcat?

Comment: Well I have fixed the other part of your code, so please upvote

Comment: Hmm, I see that this answer is now longer relevant to your heavily edited question.  You have basically changed this question to a new one after implementing my fixes - not the way it works - bye

Comment: I am new to StackOverflow and this is my first ever post. Im sorry for that.